# I want to Integrate ODBC in my Code for both linux and windows using CMakeLists.txt but its only working in windows

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-language

I am currently working on a project which requires SQL database. I want to make project platform independent so i am writing CMakeLists.txt but unfortunately its not working with linux currrently I have this part in CmakeLists.txt

```
find_package(ODBC)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}_component ${ODBC_LIBRARIES} CML)
```

I know that I have to put ifelse for platform so i am thinking in this direction

```
if (WIN32)
    find_package(ODBC)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}_component ${ODBC_LIBRARIES} CML)
endif (WIN32)


if (UNIX)
   ## dont know what to write here ?? 
endif (UNIX)
```

Ps. I am very beginner in CMake writing so I would really helpful if someone can guide me .

Comment: You may be interested in [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [FindODBC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindODBC.html):

> Find an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) include directory and library.
>
> On Windows, when building with Visual Studio, this module  assumes 
>   the  ODBC  library  is provided by the available Windows SDK.
>
> On  Unix,  this  module  allows  to  search for ODBC library provided
>   by unixODBC or iODBC implementations of ODBC API.

Comment: You got it :)  I just missed what each libraries does